# How to generate random UUID per group of records in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, uuid

HOw can i create random UUID per group of records ?

for ex, how can I create random uuid per name(diff in color) in below dataset in Postgres sql ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Generate UUID for all rows, then use `max(id) over(partition by name)` to get the same id for group.

```
select max(id) over (partition by name) as id, name, age
from 
(
select  name, age, md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::uuid as id
  from ...
)s
```

Also can use  uuid-ossp for UUID generation like in @GordonLinoff answer

Answer (score 1):

First, you need [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html#id-1.11.7.53.4) to generate uuids.  This is a module you need to add in.

Then it should be pretty simple method would be:

```
select t.*, name_uuid
from t join
     (select name, uuid_generate_v4() as name_uuid
      from t
      group by name
     ) n
     using (name);
```

Comment: pg_crypto also has uuid generating function: generate_random_uuid returns a v4 uuid.